# REST API search query Obtain results

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have data from a result of a query

```
Data 
[0]  Cells 
    [0]: {key: "name" value:"abc"}
    [1]: {key: "sex" value:"f"}
    // this cell has a long list of array
```

How to get the value if the key is "name" ?

I attemped

```
result=res.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;

     debugger; 
     var a=result[10].Cells[8]; // This doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the value i need by

```
result[i].Cells[14].Value
```

The concept is like this

```
//fetch json data alove
 result=res.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;

            for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            this.ppl.push({
                   jobtitle:result[i].Cells[14].Value
                    // and more 
                    });
            }
//code continues.
```

Would there be a better way to get the value ?
e.g. I want to go over the array and search if the Value of "Key" is name, Get the Value of "Value"